# Failed to install npm for laravel 5.6

Tags: php, node.js, laravel-5, npm-install

npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Project\council\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.16.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-07-08T11_43_43_669Z-debug-0.log

Comment: You have error that has more info in `2022-07-08T11_43_43_669Z-debug-0.log` file. Show that file content

Comment: can't found this file.

Comment: Enable hidden files showing on Windows first, because `AppData` is hidden by default

Comment: Basically I'm trying to run (github council) project  by JafferyWay. I thought it can be issue of node version then I tried multiple old versions of node but each version throughs different error. This errors is from latest LTE

Comment: FILE 
verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Muham\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@8.13.2
2 info using node@v16.16.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Muham\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Muham\Desktop\Project\council\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
etc etc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believed this is a node version issue, try to downgrade your node version, you can use version manager(`nvm`) to switch to another node versions.